# How to return "N/A" when driver can't find xpath of an element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I have this specific url from a list of urls and this specifc one has a different xpath format than other urls in terms of where "Brand Name" is located.
So I wanted to return something like a string "N/A" or None but I get the error of

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
or
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

which is probably from calling brand_name.text on None or calling brand_name.text on "N/A"

I can't change calling brand_name.text in my row = {} as that does its job perfectly with other urls
I also don't want to make another code finding the xpath of the brand_name in this specific url as there are going to be other urls with other different formats for the brand_name.

What would I need to do to make brand_name return something like "N/A" when the driver can't find xpath to it?

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

chromedriver = " - path to chrome driver -"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
rows = []

url = https://www.amazon.com/BEAKEY-Foundation-Blending-Flawless-Multi-colored/dp/B01F36JEXE/ref=sr_1_22?dchild=1&keywords=cosmetics&qid=1625014752&sr=8-22

driver.get(url)
    
    # BRAND NAME
    try:
        brand_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="a-spacing-small"][.//*[contains(.,"Brand")]]/td[@class="a-span9"]/span')
    except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
        brand_name = None
    
    # SELLER
    seller = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//span[@class="a-truncate-cut"]/span[@class="tabular-buybox-text"])[2]')
    
    # DELIVERY DATE
    delivery_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="mir-layout-DELIVERY_BLOCK"]/div[@class="a-spacing-base"]/b')
   
    
    row = { 'Brand Name': brand_name.text,
            'Seller': seller.text,
            'Delivery Date': delivery_date.text
          }
    
    if brand_name is not None:
          row['Brand Name'] = brand_name.text
    else:
          row['Brand Name'] = "N/A"
    
    
    
    rows.append(row)

driver.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.to_csv('Result2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error(s) as properly formatted text in the question. (2) The indentation is not right. Better just copy and paste the original code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call text on something that isn't a webelement. Maybe something like:

```
if brand_name is not None:
    brand_name_or_none = brand_name.text
else:
    brand_name_or_none = "N/A"

row = { 'Brand Name': brand_name_or_none,
        'Seller': seller.text,
        'Delivery Date': delivery_date.text
      }
```